# d3.js mouseover events clashing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using Christophe Viau's d3.js tooltip helper:

https://gist.github.com/milroc/2975255

but also want to trigger other events on mouseover, not just a tooltip, specifically I want to modify the circle itself, so I tried:

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.call(d3.helper.tooltip(function(d,i){return d.name;}))
.attr("r", 12)
 .call(force.drag)
 .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");});
```

Either one works by itself, but not together. I tried editing the tooltip helper, but I got errors. I added variations on these to the tooltip helper:

```
var newvar = function(d,i) {d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");}
var newvar = function(selection) {d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");}
```

Does anyone know what the proper way is to phrase this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated my 10 months old code ;) http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2973775

The part you need is the [event namespacing](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#wiki-dispatch_on), so you can apply multiple events to the same element without clashing:

```
.on('mousemove.tooltip', ...
```